# Select pandas df rows based on position of the substring

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas

I have been doing selection of Pandas rows with substrings like this:

```
df[df['key'].str.contains("mykey")]
```

Which is fine, but what if I don´t want to know if the value contains the substring, but I really need to specify the position?

For instance, if I have:

```
KEY
02038895
01024876
```

How can I do so a selection gives me back only rows where `value[2:4] == '02'`

I have tried:

```
df = df[df["KEY"].str[2:4] == "02"]
```

But I am getting:

```
TypeError: invalid type comparison
```

I am comparing strings, so I am not sure about the Type Error. Isn´t this the right way to accomplish this comparison?

Comment: `df = pd.DataFrame({'KEY': ['02038895', '01024876']}); df[df['KEY'].str[2:4] == '02']` seems to work fine for me. Can you show a bit more of your code/data to reproduce the error?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

this should work:

```
df[df.astype(str).KEY.str[1:3] == '02']
Out[34]: 
       KEY
1  1024876
```

Comment: Thanks, it was a type problem as you suggest, so casting as string helped to avoid the issue. I wasn´t casting properly before.